# Sometimes `90-updates-available` doesn't show the number of updates available upon login?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, login

I just figured out that the program `90-updates-available` (as in `/etc/update-motd.d/90-updates-available`) sometimes behaves strangely, on ALL my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machines (not sure for other releases).

The function of this program is to show this:

```
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

Usually this message is shown upon terminal (tty/SSH) login but you can also call it manually and you will see this message too.

There are two strange parts:

I. This message sometimes doesn't appear when I login, which means I just get other messages except this. For example, if I SSH into `localhost`, I usually get this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-51-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

Last login: Fri Mar 11 16:54:19 2016 from localhost
```

But sometimes I just get this:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-51-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

Last login: Fri Mar 11 16:54:19 2016 from localhost
```

According to my experience, the second situation usually happens after I successfully installed/upgraded some packages using `apt-get` or the Update Manager. However, if I wait for a few minutes and run `apt-get update`, the **next next** (double "next", not a typo) time I login to the terminal the messages will re-appear like what it normally does.

Why is this happening? Can I make it to always appear?

II. The second strange thing is, this message is not up-to-date, more precisely, it is "one logon" behind.

For example, if this time, I see 4 packages can be updated, and I run `apt-get upgrade` in the same terminal, then the next time when I login to terminal (tty/SSH), it still shows "4 packages". Then I don't do anything but exit, and the next time when I login the message will disappear (as in part I).

If this time, the message didn't show up, and I run `sudo apt-get update` in the same terminal, the next time I login it won't show up either, but the "next next" time I login it will tell me how many packages can be updated.

Why is this happening?